# Asynchronous vs synchronous messagin

Tags: asynchronous, messaging, synchronous

What is difference between Asynchronous vs synchronous messaging (java) and how does it impact way in which messaging sender / receiver is implemented.
how does a J2EE architecture decides to choose either.

Answer (score 1):

The Sun J2EE Blueprints cover this.

http://java.sun.com/blueprints/guidelines/designing_enterprise_applications_2e/eis-tier/eis-tier4.html

This particular article discusses interoperability with an EIS, but the principles are the same when using it for your own applications.